# JavaScript function not disabling button

Tags: javascript

the html code: (td because it's within a table)

```
<td><button onclick=setSquare("ul")id="bul">upper left</button></td>
```

the javascript code:

```
function Gid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function setSquare(w) {
    Gid("b"+w).disabled=true;
}
```

I'm trying to get it to disable the button using a familiar syntax that all the buttons share ("bul","bum","bur",etc) so it will automatically have "b", then add w, which is what's being passed as the parameter.

Comment: `<button onclick='setSquare("ul")' id="bul">`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`<td><button onclick=setSquare("ul")id="bul">upper left</button></td>`

to this:

`<td><button onclick='setSquare("ul")' id="bul">upper left</button></td>`

OR

`<td><button onclick="setSquare('ul')" id="bul">upper left</button></td>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad way to write JS. Inline JS in not encouraged by W3C, what you could do at least is:

```
<input type="button" value="foo" id="bul"/>
<input type="button" value="bar" id="bum"/>
<input type="button" value="baz" id="bur"/>

var p = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button'][id^='b']");
[].forEach.call(p, function(el) { el.onclick = function() { el.disabled = true } })
```

I am a terrible JS programmer , but there are better ways to do it, like putting the buttons in a parent with a class and using `event delegation`